# copy command in postgresql to append data

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.1, copy

I am executing `copy` command from a function

```
execute 'copy (select * from tableName) to ''/tmp/result.txt'''
```

It works fine. But, `tableName` is dynamic and will be having more tables (iterating in a loop). `result.txt` is having only the last iteration (table) data.

I could do, if I had to, via the command line with `\o` or `>>` by appending to a file. But, I have to use the function.

I read http://shuber.io/reading-from-the-filesystem-with-postgres/.  It suggests a solution using temporary tables. Can I do something similar, but without temp tables? (I must avoid archive logs).  Will creating a temp table create archive logs?

Is there any way to do appending with `copy` command in a function?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you cannot (easily) do that (at least on your PostgreSQL version, see Daniel's [answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/149774/6219)).  What you definitely can, however, is changing your approach, and do a `UNION ALL` from all those tables in the query part of your `COPY`.  This means there is no looping, but you have to construct your query from the collected table names.

The result would look like

```
COPY (SELECT * FROM table1
      UNION ALL
      SELECT * FROM table2
      ...) 
    TO tmp/result.txt;
```

**Notes:**

- there is no such thing as a `psql` function. `psql` is a client to PostgreSQL.  It has built in commands (basically everything starting with `\`), however.
- it is not so clear what you mean by 'archive logs'.  If it is the write-ahead log (WAL), then with the above approach you don't have to worry about it.  Otherwise, you can use [unlogged tables](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createtable.html#SQL-CREATETABLE-UNLOGGED).
- if the tables are big, there is a chance your system will write (a lot of) temp files.  This might make the execution not so fast.

Comment: thanks for point me out. I aware of that ``psql``, but I used to be and didn't realize while typing. Yes, its WAL, i need to avoid that. i will check the table's creation option(s) and will post which suits / solves my scenario.

Comment: ``unlogged`` says, fast than ordinary tables and not crash-safe. Its fine for my scenario. where i can find about the temp files creation. is there any documentation page?

Answer (score 8):

Assuming a Unix system

### with PostgreQSL 9.3 or newer

Use the PROGRAM clause with `cat` as the program.

In the context of a loop in the plpgsql language, where `tableName` would be a variable, the invocation would typically look like:

```
execute format(
 'copy (select * from %I) to PROGRAM ''cat >>/tmp/result.txt''',
       tableName);
```

This would append the results to the end of `/tmp/result.txt` instead of overwriting the file.

Or if `tableName` is not a variable but directly the name of an actual table, the simpler following invocation will do:

```
COPY tableName to PROGRAM 'cat >>/tmp/result.txt';
```

### with older versions of PostgreSQL

A named pipe can be used by a separate process to concatenate results.
Example:

```
$ mkfifo /tmp/pgfifo
$ while true; do cat /tmp/pgfifo >>/tmp/result.txt; done
```

This last command will block. Let it run until all the results are accumulated, then it can be terminated with ^C or kill.

In SQL, the fifo has to be fed with:

```
  COPY tableName to '/tmp/pgfifo'
```

or if the context is plpgsql code where `tableName` is a variable:

```
  execute 'COPY ' || quote_ident(tableName) || ' TO ''tmp/pgfifo''';
```

Comment: if newer version supports, really its cool. But unfortunately, I'm using `9.1` . As of now, I'm using `unlogged` option and doing testing.

Comment: In case anyone else is trying this, on PostgreSQL 15, I had to remove the `execute ''` part to get it working.

Comment: @Ray: that's because in the context of the question, `tableName` is dynamic so the code is plpgsql (procedural) to build the sql query and then execute it. I've edited this answer to clarify that.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a Windows alternative to @Daniel Vérité's 9.3 answer

```
execute 'copy (select * from tableName) to PROGRAM ''findstr "^" >> c:\somePath\result.txt'''
```

I borrowed this findstr technique from [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/853718).