# Can copy command in postgresql append data to a file?

Tags: postgresql, copy

I want to add some data from a postgresql table to a text file. But already some data is present in the file. I do not want to delete that data. Is it possible?
The questions asked earlier were the one in which the table name was dynamic. But in mine, it is not. All I am asking for is to append data. Also, the answer given is for Unix, not windows.

Comment: The questions asked earlier were the one in which the table name was dynamic. But in mine, it is not. All I am asking for is to append data. Also, the answer given is for Unix, not windows.

Comment: [This answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/149774/1822) uses a hardcoded table name and will work on Windows as well (if you use a `cat` version for Windows, probably works with `type` as well)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I used this command - COPY TEST TO PROGRAM 'cat >>D:\pg_hbaOriginalModified.conf'     and got the following error - 'ERROR:  program "cat >>D:\pg_hbaOriginalModified.conf" failed
DETAIL:  child process exited with exit code 1
SQL state: 38000'        Can you help with what does this mean?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name One more thing, if my target file contains some comments, and then has the data in a tabular form, is it possible to preserve those comments in the file too.